# What is error in this code?

Tags: iphone, if-statement, compiler-errors, nsmutablearray

```
for(NSDictionary *feed in Feeds)
{
  NSString *feedName=[feed objectForKey:@"name"];
                                if(listofBusiness==nil)
{
                                    listofBusiness=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
                                    if([listofBusiness indexOfObject:feedName] !=NSNotFound)
        {
        [listofBusiness addObject:feedName];
        [feedName release];
        feedName=nil;   
                                }

                            }
```

in this code when compiler comes on this statement

> if([listofBusiness indexOfObject:feedName] !=NSNotFound)

then not go into codition and go to increment in for loop so that any element is not added in array.what is error in this code?

Comment: Unrelated to your question which has a good answer, the memory management in your code is all messed up. Run the static analyser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic appears to be inverted - you probably want it to add the elemement when

```
[listofBusiness indexOfObject:feedName] == NSNotFound
```

But at the moment you have the opposite - you only try to add the object when it is 'not not found' - i.e. when it is already present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

indexOfObject is not working for an array

Try with containsObject method of an array.

Example :

```
         if([listofBusiness containsObject:feedName]) {
             // your code
         }
```